# Converting POLYGON binary to array of lat and long values

Tags: php, mysql

I need to convert POLYGON binary data to an array of lat and long values.

The reason why I decided not to use MySQL's function such as `AsText` is because I am having to take extra steps to parse information into correct format hence slowing down the whole process. `AsText` adds extra 0.4-0.5 seconds to the query time. i.e. 1338 results with AsText 0.422 seconds and without 0.078 seconds. Also, looping through an array of data, to put items into lat and long array, takes process time to 1.2 seconds. Due to which AsText is very slow.

I have created a small method to perform unpack based on the information here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-internal-format

The problem is that sometimes `$unpack` will return an extra array item due to which I am having to check if `count($unpack)` is odd or not. *Note: `ST_AsText` returns correct number of elements excluding extra item.*

I am also not confident about the correctness of the lat/long results, but I think it could be due to the issue above.

```
        $unpack = unpack("x4/corder/Ltype/d*", $polygon, 0);
        array_shift($unpack);
        array_shift($unpack);

        if (count($unpack)%2) {
            array_shift($unpack);
        }

        $data = array_chunk($unpack, 2);
        $return = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
            $return[] = [
                'lat' => $data[$i][0],
                'lng' => $data[$i][1],
            ];
        }

        return $return;
```

In the MySQL my polygon is stored as `GEOMETRY` data type.

Example data in the DB:

```
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
```

Comment: "AsText adds extra 0.4-0.5 seconds to the query time!" - For how many rows?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel 1338 results with AsText = 0.422 sec and without 0.078 sec

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include (hardcoded) values for `$polygon` (something like `$polygon = hex2bin('0000..')`). Include both cases (even and odd count). Also post the result you'd like to get from the code. In best case someone would just need to C&P your code and fix it.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I have added an example

Comment: Seems they don't store it as WKB. There is an extra byte at the beginning ([see the difference](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wHbT5V2fepUQkzD724g2ZM/0)). Also see this [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69798). Do you have an example without that byte?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I dont have an example without extra byte(s) while using `Geometry` data type. `Polygon` data type does not have the same problem. I have tried removing extra bytes using PHP, but it caused decoded data to have one lat or long to be inaccurate from time to time.

Comment: The issue is to do with SRID, had to make it 0 when inserting data.

Answer (score 2):

This was driving me nuts as well, here's the correct unpack:

```
unpack('VSRID/corder/ltype/Lnum_rings/Lnum_points/d*', $value);
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkb-format

The MySQL docs cover the first 4 bytes being the SRID, next byte being the byte order, the following 4 bytes as the type info.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/ea7d2e2d16ac03afdd9cb72a972a95981107bf51/sql/gis/wkb.cc

What I had to dig through the MySQL source for was that before the coordinates there's an unsigned integer for the number of polygon rings, and another unsigned integer for the number of coordinate pairs.

Comment: thanks for sharing your ideas, it really helped a lot